# Matching x chars from the beginning using regex

Tags: regex, delphi

i m trying to make rename program with delphi and need to know if it s possible to match some specified number of characters from the beginning, using regex.

for example if the string is FileName.txt and the specific number is 6
it should match FileNa

i also need a pattern to match string from a specific number to the end.

i would be glad if answers include descriptions because i would like to learn regex coding.

Comment: What qualifies as a "character"? If it's just letters then `^\w{6}` will do it but I think you'll want something more strict than that.

Comment: i mean a string that contains all characters that could be used for file names.

Comment: Sounds like you just want to use `Pos()`

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is generally a premium resource for learning regular expressions.

Comment: You want to use plain `Copy()`. Example: `Copy('ABCD', 1, 2)` returns the string `'12'`. No need for regex here.

Comment: [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html). Sorry I couldn't fine a better link.

Comment: Well there is nothing wrong with using regex for this problem if your intention is to learn regular expressions. Start simple, and this problem allows you to start with a simple approach and build on top of it. Other than that, I agree there are better solutions for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Delphi XE, regular expression functionality is build in with the `TRegEx` class. If you use an earlier version of Delphi you can find a library here, where you can also find more about the Delphi XE support: http://www.regular-expressions.info/delphi.html

This regular expression matches up to 6 characters until the `.` separating the extension from the rest of the file name.

```
^([^\.]{1,6})[^\.]*(?:\..*)?$
```

Given the input: *FileName.txt*
Group 1 would be: *FileNa*

Given the input: *File.txt*
Group 1 would be: *File*

The expression uses grouping to capture the first 6 characters. The code in Delphi XE would look something like:

```
var
    Regex: TPerlRegEx;
    ResultString: string;

Regex := TPerlRegEx.Create;
try
    Regex.RegEx := '^([^\.]{1,6})[^\.]*(?:\..*)?$';
    Regex.Options := [];
    Regex.Subject := SubjectString;
    if Regex.Match then begin
        if Regex.GroupCount >= 1 then begin
            ResultString := Regex.Groups[1];
        end
        else begin
            ResultString := '';
        end;
    end
    else begin
        ResultString := '';
    end;
finally
    Regex.Free;
end;
```

For instance the filename: FileName.txt will be matched with: **FileNa** (group 1)

I'll try to explain the regular expression I have used, although there are probably better expressions out there:

```
^ # Match beginning of line
( # Begin a group (enables us to capture the contents alone)
  [^\.] # Capture any character that is not a '.'
  {1,6} # Capture anything from 1 to 6 of these characters (6 if possible)
) # Close the group
[^\.] # Match any character that is not '.' (again)
* # Match this 0 or more times
(?: # Begin a group that we do not wish to capture
  \. # Capture the character '.' (the extension separator)
  .* # Capture any character 0 or more times
) # Close the group
? # Match this group 0 or 1 time (it is either there or not)
$ # Match the end of line
```

To the next part of your question, creating a pattern to match a string from a specific number to the end:

```
^(?:.{6})?(.*)$
```

Given the input: *This is a test*
Group 1 would be: *s a test*

In this example the specific number is *6*, change it to whatever number you are looking for. Again I've used groups to get the contents of the matched text. The first group is a none capturing group, meaning we are not interested in its content, only that we need it to be there. If we are still talking about filenames you can use the following regular expression:

```
^(?:[^\.]{6})([^\.]*)(?:\..*)?$
```

Given the input: *FileName.txt*
Group 1 would be: *me*

This is a modification of the first regular expression, where I've made the first group none capturing, told it to be *6* characters long (again change to whatever number suits you). And excluded the extension from the captured text.

Remember that regular expressions are easier to compose than to read. I always found that: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a good source of information, besides this book has helped me a great deal: [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596528126?green=27102901097&cmp=af-mybuy-9780596528126.IP).

Comment: thanks for the helps. i want to use regex for two reasons. first, i want to learn regex. second it's simpler than programming language code. at least it's simple for view. i don't know if it is faster but regex is going to save my time and effort.

Comment: You're great man. thanks for the detailed answer. i m happy for being here, talking to experts.

Comment: Again thanks a lot. but when i test this code ^(?:[^\.]{6})([^\.]*)(?:\..*)?$ it matches all string. it would be better for me to get a pattern that matches from specified position to other specified position before .extension

Sincerely

Comment: Are you remembering to only extract the match of group 1?

Comment: If you only want it to match part of the string, remove the `^` and `$` from the beginning and end, and if you do not want it to include the extension remove the `(?:\..*)?` from it.

Comment: sorry, i didn t know much about the groups. it works fine now.

Answer (score 4):

```
^.{6}
```

Will match the first 6 characters, but will not match if there are fewer than 6.

```
^.{1,6}
```

Will match the first 6 characters (as many as it can up to 6), but will not match if the string is empty.

`.` means to match any character (including path delimiters, in your case).  You can replace `.` with `\w` if you only want letters, numbers, and underscore.

```
^\w{1,6}
```

Comment: i also need it to match from a specific position to anther one. or to the end.

Comment: Why do you need a regex?  What you need is substring.  Are you forced to use regex?